# No Wifi Adapter found using externel wifi dongle

Tags: wifi

Im using linux Ubuntu 20.04. My computer has only enthernet but I needed also wi-fi, so I bought wifi dongle 8188eu. First i tried installing drivers and maybe I succedded(or maybe not). Now it is is showing me the wifi to turn it on but also that 'No wifi adapter is found". Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the output of `sudo rfkill list` , please.

Answer (score 0):

`rtl8188eu` driver can be installed from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/kablosuz):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/kablosuz
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8188eu-dkms
sudo modprobe -v 8188eu
```

Comment: I intalled it but know i dont have the option to turn on the wifi

Comment: @MartinS.Dinev See my edit, please.